# solarium add filter query on multiple fields with OR operator

Tags: solr, solarium

I'm new in Solr search, Can anyone help me to add multiple fields OR condition I got solutions in solr but I can't implement this in solarium. 
I have fields

```
1. name
2. username
3. email
```

I want to convert this in Solarium filter query like I use single field for this

```
$query->createFilterQuery('name')->setQuery('name:*' . $keyword . '*');
```

I want its result like

```
fq=(name:*abc* OR username:*abc* OR email:*email*)
```

Please help me to add multiple fields with OR operator for match if any one matches in any of three field then return me result.

Comment: You can't use setQuery('name:*..* OR foo:*..* OR bar:*..*')? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Disjunction Max aka DisMax might point you in the right direction.  SitePoint has put together a simple tutorial here: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-solarium-solr-search-implementation/

An example with the parameters named in your question:

```
$dismax = $query->getDisMax ();
$dismax->setQueryFields ('name username email');
```